# CssEmbed generates exception on bootstrap_less file

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, yui-compressor

I'm currently following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5om81wXYIns

It's about learning Symfony 2.3, and right now is demonstrating how to set up Twitter Bootstrap and also how to use assetic with cssembed, to compress all css and javascript code in to 1 file each.

I'm working on Windows7, I can't get a linux machine or VM where I'm at.

The config file can be found here: http://mossco.co.uk/symfony-2/symfony-2-and-bootstrap-3-assetic-config-and-base-html-template-file/

I of course changed the java path to this:

```
java: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin'
```

An exception is thrown on the file

> ../web/assetic/bootstrap_less.less

The exception being:

> Failed to assign arg @list: line: 50

That also means the file is never generated, so I don't really know where to look for the error. And even then, I don't know how to fix it. I've got all this listed in the composer.json file and it has been updated:

```
"leafo/lessphp": "*",
"twitter/bootstrap": "*",
"components/jquery": "dev-master"
```

Does anyone have an incling of what might be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a problem with lessphp, not been able to read sintax properly at some point in the v3.0.2 of bootstrap. (issue [opened here](https://github.com/leafo/lessphp/issues/491))

If you keep using lessphp, you will need to downgrade from v3.0.2 to v3.0.0. Modify the require line for twitter bootstrap in your composer.json file:

> "twitter/bootstrap": "v3.0.0"

Then remember to update composer after that